# Can you find the key move?

Tags: no-computers, chess

I've created this chess problem for today. it's White to move and their pawns move upward. Can you find the key move? Have fun, and no computers are allowed!

**Checkmate In 5 Moves**

[image]

**Addendum 11/6/2021:** The below answers have the correct key move, but neither has solved the mate in five yet!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if black has a good way to prevent

> the white king walking to f3 to support the bishop giving mate on g2.
>  1. Kd3

Black can try

> 1... Ne6
>  threatening to put the knight on g5 to prevent the king from entering.
>
>  Now, if white takes on e6, the white king does not have enough time to get to f3 as after
>  2. Bxe6 b5
>  3. Ke4 b6
>  4. Kf3
>  black is in stalemate.

So, it seems that plan doesn't quite work. However, white has another way to deliver mate:

> Bring the king over to f4 instead and use the other bishop to deliver mate.
>  2. Ke4 Ng5+
>  3. Kf4 Ne6+ (otherwise 4. Bxg4#)
>  4. Bxe6 b5
>  5. Bxg4#

Comment: You're first move is correct, but your third one is not, and please give lines for all Black's moves.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not

> mate in 5

but

> mate in 6

With the first move being

> 1. Kd3

Analyzing all of black options:
After this move, black cannot play

> 1.b5 or 1.Ne8

bacause in these cases

> black has no way to stop
>  2. Ke4 with the idea 3.Kf3 and 4.Bxg2#

One possibility for black is the move

> 1. Nh5

In this case, white cannot play

> 2.Ke4 because of 2.Ng3 negates every checkmate in 5 or 6: 3.Kf3 Nxf1 or 3.Nxg3 Kxg3)

but has the option to play

> 2.Rxh5 forcing mate in 6 after 2. b5 3.e8=Q b4 4.Rb5 Bg3 5.Qh8+ Bh4 6.Rf3#

> 2.e8=Q which is also mate in 6, forcing 2.Nf4+ (because of 2.b5 3.Qxh5 b4 4. Qxh4#) and forcing white to move the king somewhere, having ideas of checkmating with the queen in 2 on Qxg4# or Qxh4#. However, black does always have the option to give check at least once in all of these lines leading to a variety of forced mates in 6

Looking at the other possible first moves for black:

> 1.Ne6

> is also mate in 6: It leads to 2.Bxe6 b5 3.e8=Q b4 4.d5. Here, black has three options,
>  4.Nxe5+ 5.Qxe5 Kg4 6.Be6#  or
>  4.Nf6 5.Qe6+ g4 6.Bxg2# or
>  4.Nh6 5.Qe6+ g4 6.Bxg2# (same as before)

Leaving just

> 1.Nf5

> which is also mate in 6 after
>  2.Bxf5 e5 3.e8=Q e4 4.Be4 and black having the options
>  4.Nxe5+ 5.Qxe5 Kg4 6.Qf5# or
>  black moving the knight to either f6 or h6 which is followed by
>  5.Qe6+ Ng4 6.Bxg2#

Comment: Your key is correct, but there is indeed a mate in 5. Promotion does take place, but you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: @RewanDemontay You should give the check, though, as you only asked for the key. The rest is a courtesy.

Comment: Um, absolutely not @Weckar E. This is not a correct solution even if the key is correct. You have to find the whole solution-the key is hard, so that's what the main attention was focused on.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Then perhaps the question should be clarified. You ask for the key, you claim this answer gave the correct one.